# Is it possible to convert SWRevealViewController to UISplitViewController when I run on iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I have an app created on **SWRevealViewController** on iPhone but now Client wants to create iPad app. And all Viewcontroller created using XIBs.

He wants UISplitViewController like UI(Landscape Mode) which is difficult to convert whole app.

When I run app on iPad everything works Perfect on SWRevealViewController.

but I want to implement UI Like UISplitViewController.

Is it possible to convert **SWRevealViewController** To **UISplitViewController** without changing Navigation code.

Is there any feature available in  **SWRevealViewController** to handle UI as **UISplitViewController** ?

Any help Will be appreciated

Comment: just hide the navigationbarbutton and trigger it manually

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger the UIBarButton while launch the particular viewController

```
[barButtonItem.target performSelector:barButtonItem.action];

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   here you are adding the reveal view controller.

    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
if (revealViewController) {
    [self.sidebarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
    [self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector(revealToggle:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer: self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
}
   ->here hide the uibarbutton so that nobody know there is menu.
   ->then programatically trigger the uibarbutton click event as i mentioned above.
   ->then do enable of you uibarbutton =false ;//for static purpose 
}
```

Comment: https://cdn5.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/catbot-667x500.png we want display like this in SWRevealViewController on iPad

Comment: @user9988 wait a minute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114086/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-user9988).